# Restricted Mean Survival Time Oaxaca Decomposition

Tags: survival, blinder-oaxaca

Are there methods that estimate restricted mean survival time with Oaxaca Decomposition or something similar to Oaxaca Decomposition?

Comment: Look at Guo and Basse, [The Generalized Oaxaca-Blinder Estimator](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2021.1941053) for how far one might push this approach in other than linear models. My sense (without a lot of study yet) is that it might be possible in some circumstances for parametric survival models but not for Cox models.